# Sending xml via soapclient in PHP

Tags: php, xml, soap

I am very new to using Web Services and understanding XML. If you feel I should read some tutorials or documentation I'd be greatful if you could supply some links.

I am trying to execute a simple function via a web service,

In the documentation that was provided I have the following information...

Web Service Input Parameters:

**id** , data type = xs:string , lenght: 10

**password** , data type = xs:string , lenght: 25

**group** , data type = xs:string , length: 20

**orderxml** , data type = xs:string , length: 2^16

I have been given sample xml for the last paramater , when I try and run the function I get the following error.

> Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [a:InternalServiceFault]
>   Value cannot be null. Parameter name: property in

```
 $client = new SoapClient('http://www.example.com/service?wsdl');
 $xml = '<samplexml> </samplexml>';
 $response = $client->Import(
 array(
    'Id' => '1234',
    'password' => '123456',
    'group' => 'test1',
    'orderxml' => $xml

));
```

When I try

```
 $response = $client->Import('test', 'test');
```

I get the following...

I tried the second one thinking perhaps I need to send raw XML?

> Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [a:DeserializationFailed]
>   The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the
>   message: Error in deserializing body of request message for operation
>   'Import'. End element 'Body' from namespace
>   'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' expected. Found element
>   'param1' from namespace ''. Line 2, position 162. in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adrian -

From the snippets you gave, there is not much to determine about what you are trying to do. Without knowing the exact nature of the WSDL, it is hard to say what is going on - is Import a valid request, is it in the right format, etc.

I suggest loading your WSDL into SOAPUI and verifying that your XML format is correct. This is a very useful tool in preparing your SOAP requests before actually coding them in PHP.

> http://www.soapui.org/

I would then suggest referencing the PHP manual for the SoapClient class to properly format your code.

> http://php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php

Comment: Thank you, I installed SoapUI and already it helped me alot with the XML formatting required